# Access to docker.socket using SELinux in FCOS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, selinux, coreos

### Intro

Greetings,

Since a week I'm trying to setup a **FCOS** (Fedora CoreOS) and running a **Docker Swarm** along with **SELinux** (this is my first experience with SELinux)

Containers is running great but when I'm trying to use the `/var/run/docker.socket` I'm always getting `permission denied`

```
portainer_agent.0.k9c6uqifwohk@localhost    | 2020/03/14 13:24:11 [ERROR] [main,docker] [message: Unable to retrieve information from Docker] [error: Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/info: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied]
```

I've already tried to disable SELinux (`setenforce 0`) to ensure the problem comes from SELinux,

### Info

docker.socket

```
srw-rw----. 1 root docker system_u:object_r:container_var_run_t:s0 0 Mar 14 13:14 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Here a docker-compose.yaml I'm using for my tests

```yaml
version: '3.2'

services:
  agent:
    image: portainer/agent
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:z      
      - /var/lib/docker/volumes:/var/lib/docker/volumes:z
    networks:
      - agent_network
    deploy:
      mode: global
      placement:
        constraints: [node.platform.os == linux]


networks:
  agent_network:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've finally succeeded, using dockersock.te from [this GitHub](https://github.com/dpw/selinux-dockersock)

Here the function I use in my installation script:

```sh
function fix_socket_permission()
{
    echo "Downloading docker socket policy"
    sudo rpm-ostree install policycoreutils-python-utils
    echo "Need reboot"
    # need to reboot

    curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dpw/selinux-dockersock/master/dockersock.te -o /tmp/dockersock.te

    echo "Applying policy to system"
    checkmodule -M -m -o dockersock.mod /tmp/dockersock.te
    semodule_package -o dockersock.pp -m dockersock.mod
    sudo semodule -i dockersock.pp
    rm -rf /tmp/dockersock.te
}
```

Comment: Nice find! I'd split this single function into two parts, one for setup, and one to apply the policy, so one can easily reboot in between the two functions.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike CL (Container Linux), FCOS (Fedora CoreOS) comes with SELinux "targeted" policy set to "enforced". If you are expecting the same behavior as in CL you should set "SELINUX=permissive" in /etc/selinux/config.

Here is CL /etc/selinux/config:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system on boot.

# SELINUX can take one of these three values:
#   enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#   permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#   disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive

# SELINUXTYPE can take one of these four values:
#   targeted - Only targeted network daemons are protected.
#   strict   - Full SELinux protection.
#   mls      - Full SELinux protection with Multi-Level Security
#   mcs      - Full SELinux protection with Multi-Category Security 
#              (mls, but only one sensitivity level)
SELINUXTYPE=mcs
```

Here is FCOS /etc/selinux/config:

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#     enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#     permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#     disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=enforcing
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these three values:
#     targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#     minimum - Modification of targeted policy. Only selected processes are protected. 
#     mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Comment: I figured out this solution as well, but this should is not applicable in a production environment. You can't simply turn off security enforcements to get something else working. I have been trying to properly configure SElinux security context for docker socket file, to this point, however, without success.

Answer (score 1):

You can now allow a single container to opt out of the SELinux enforcement by adding `--security-opt label=disable` to the docker command. This passes a `seccomp` profile to the container. [See details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/#pass-a-profile-for-a-container)

This is an improvement from a security perspective vs the answer which changes SELinux policy to allow all containers to mount the socket. With this approach only the single container with the flag can do it and others remain restricted.

For example:

```bash
docker run -d --name watchtower --security-opt label=disable -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:z  --restart=always containrrr/watchtower
```

Note that the `:z` on the end of the mount is potentially required to have docker setup the permissions correctly for mounting files and folders under SELinux. [See details](https://projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/)

[image]